# Metodo split e rsplit, python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Fiz esse pequeno programa para tentar simular os metodos `'split'` e `'rsplit'` do `Python`, mas quando executo ele não imprime a última frase da string. Por exemplo, se na string eu digito `'pao ou açucar ou café'` e escolho o separador `'ou'`, ele cria a lista apenas com `['pao', 'açucar']` e não imprime a ultima palavra na lista. Preciso de ajuda para encontrar o erro.

```
def separa(string):
    separador = input("Digite o separador: ")
    lista = []
    x = 0
    for i in range(string.count(separador)+1):
        palavra = ''
        for j in range(x, len(string)):

            if string[j:j+len(separador)] == separador:
                lista.append(palavra)
                x = j+len(separador)
                break

            palavra += string[j]

    return lista

string = input("Digite a string: ")
print(separa(string))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicamente o seu código apenas acrescenta na lista palavras encontradas antes de um separador. Como a sua última palavra (no caso, "café") não possui um separador (no caso, "ou") após ela, o código não entra na condição `if string[j:j+len(separador)] == separador:`, o que impede que essa última palavra seja acrescentada na lista com `lista.append(palavra)`

Comment: Acho que consegui. Tirei a variavel 'palavra' do programa e a cada vez que o primeiro for roda eu adiciono uma variavel vazia a lista e vou adicionando as letras da string ate que chegue no separador.
http://prntscr.com/kus0wn

Answer (score 1):

O problema no seu código está na condição:

```
if string[j:j+len(separador)] == separador
```

Não que ela esteja logicamente errada mas que ela estipula que somente se a `string` atual na iteração for igual ao separador a palavra então armazenada na variável `palavra` deve ser então adicionada ao final da lista mas a questão é que no seu exemplo dado `'pao ou açucar ou café'` café vem após o separador logo não será adicionado ao final da lista imprimindo assim como resultado `['pao', 'açucar']`. Uma forma que pode ser feita é adicionar a palavra antes de retornar a lista dessa forma:

```
def separa(string):
    separador = input("Digite o separador: ")
    lista = []
    x = 0
    for i in range(string.count(separador)+1):
        palavra = ''
        for j in range(x, len(string)):

            if string[j:j+len(separador)] == separador:
                lista.append(palavra)
                x = j+len(separador)
                break

            palavra += string[j]
    lista.append(palavra) # Adiciona a última palavra 
    return lista

string = input("Digite a string: ")
print(separa(string))
```

Espero ter ajudado.